# In Google Cloud Natural Language, does setting the Document.Type to HTML affect the way the API breaks down sentences?

Tags: nlp, google-cloud-platform

In other words, if I submit an HTML document to Google Cloud Natural Language API, and I specify the document type as `HTML` instead of `PLAIN_TEXT`, does it affect the way Google Cloud NL breaks down sentences?

For example:

```
<h3>Wholemeal pasta</h3> <p>They are absolutely amazing.</p>
```

Is this considered as:

```
Wholemeal pasta They are absolutely amazing.
```

Or more of two sentences:

```
Wholemeal pasta. They are absolutely amazing.
```

If anybody has any idea, great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [document type](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/rest/v1beta2/documents#type) in Google Cloud Natural Language API is a field that determines the type of text that is being processed. It will mainly differentiate `PLAIN_TEXT` from `HTML` documents, which will in fact interpret the format of the document in order to obtain better results when analyzing the content.

Then, using the example you shared ( `<h3>Wholemeal pasta</h3> <p>They are absolutely amazing.</p>` ), and just by running some sample queries against the API, it can be proved that the API will process that text as two independent sentences if tagged as `HTML`.

Below I share the results of running the query (through the APIs Explorer) with the two different document types:

· [Using PLAIN_TEXT document type](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/natural%20/language/v1/language.documents.analyzeSentiment?_h=3&resource=%257B%250A%20%20%2522document%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%2522content%2522%253A%20%2522%253Ch3%253EWholemeal%20pasta%253C%252Fh3%253E%20%253Cp%253EThey%20are%20absolutely%20amazing.%253C%252Fp%253E%2522%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%2522type%2522%253A%20%2522PLAIN_TEXT%2522%250A%20%20%257D%250A%257D&): only one sentence is processed, with `sentiment.magnitude = 0.9` and `sentiment.score = 0.9`:

```
{
 "documentSentiment": {
  "magnitude": 0.9,
  "score": 0.9
 },
 "language": "en",
 "sentences": [
  {
   "text": {
    "content": "<h3>Wholemeal pasta</h3> <p>They are absolutely amazing.</p>",
    "beginOffset": -1
   },
   "sentiment": {
    "magnitude": 0.9,
    "score": 0.9
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

· [Using HTML document type](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/natural%20/language/v1/language.documents.analyzeSentiment?_h=4&resource=%257B%250A%20%20%2522document%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%2522content%2522%253A%20%2522%253Ch3%253EWholemeal%20pasta%253C%252Fh3%253E%20%253Cp%253EThey%20are%20absolutely%20amazing.%253C%252Fp%253E%2522%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%2522type%2522%253A%20%2522HTML%2522%250A%20%20%257D%250A%257D&): two sentences are processed, with `sentiment.magnitude = 0.1` and `sentiment.score = 0.1`, and then `sentiment.magnitude = 0.9` and `sentiment.score = 0.9`

```
{
 "documentSentiment": {
  "magnitude": 1.1,
  "score": 0.5
 },
 "language": "en",
 "sentences": [
  {
   "text": {
    "content": "Wholemeal pasta",
    "beginOffset": -1
   },
   "sentiment": {
    "magnitude": 0.1,
    "score": 0.1
   }
  },
  {
   "text": {
    "content": "They are absolutely amazing.",
    "beginOffset": -1
   },
   "sentiment": {
    "magnitude": 0.9,
    "score": 0.9
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Let me also recommend you the [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/natural%20/language/v1/) tool in order to test the functionalities of any Google API you would like to work with.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks for being so prompt and concise!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @dsesto do you know why many of the times magnitude and score of the sentiment happens to be zero? does it mean neutral? also does < -0.25 mean negative all the time for score and > 0.25 mean positive for score? basically how do you decide if sentiment is +, - or neutral based on magnitude and score?

Comment: @MonaJalal to begin with, I think you can have a look at [this documentation entry](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/basics#interpreting_sentiment_analysis_values), where there is an explanation to understand how to interpret magnitude and score.